# NSString convert string to NSData using encoding

Tags: ios, encoding

I have got small issue in my app.

I make NSMutableURLRequest and send body to my webserice.

```
jsonRequest = @"{\"s\":\"deón\"}";

NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonRequest UTF8String] length:[jsonRequest length]];
```

I need change "ó" symbol to \u00F3.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you another way around if you want to deploy on target >=iOS5. It involves more steps, but you can be sure about the correct result, it's less error prone.

```
NSDictionary * jsonDict = @{ @"s" : @"deón" };    
NSData * requestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDict options:0 error:nil];
```

Comment: it for iOS 4.3, so i need solution for all version

Comment: I think that Vishal answer would be fine

Answer (score 0):

convert in UTF-8

```
    NSData *data = [arrayString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it will near to your requirement

```
 NSString *jsonRequest = @"{\"s\":\"deón\"}";

 const char *c = [jsonRequest cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
```